# Are there international car ferries in the Caribbean?

Tags: international-travel, automobiles, ferries, caribbean

Is it all possible to plan a road trip in the Caribbean? [Trinidad & Tobago](http://www.tntisland.com/ferry.html) seems to have a ferry, but that is within one country.

I am looking for a ferry enabling me to do a road trip through islands of multiple countries.

Comment: This question didn't age well, all links are like gone and don't work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

There are some but they all cover short distances, often only within 1 country as you have seen.

The ones I've found...

- [Bahamas Ferries](http://www.bahamasferries.com/) has car services from the Nassau to Andros, Eleuthera, Exumas and Abacos
- One from Punta Sam to Isla Mujeres in Mexico
- Apparently an international one from La Guiria in Venezuela to Chaguaramas in Trinidad and Tobago (although I can't find details)
- [T&T Port Authority](http://www.ttitferry.com/schedule.php?mid=3) operate a car ferry service between Port of Spain, Trinidad, and Scarborough

If you plot those on a map you'll see the coverage leaves a lot to be desired. There are probably other services but I doubt you could string together enough for an island-hopping "road trip".

Surely [a sailing tour](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sailing+tours+of+Caribbean) would be better anyway?